# WSO2IS does not respect the requested GET binding in SAML2

Tags: wso2, identity, saml, wso2-identity-server

The SAML2 request is sent to WSO2 Identity Server with HTTP-GET binding, but it still POSTs the response. Any idea to let WSO2IS respect the request?

```
[2014-03-06 17:52:25,961] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil} -  Request message <samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="_73d5b9c1-d448-4076-9e9d-98767f1e2a2d" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2014-03-06T17:52:21" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-GET" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://host.tld/java-saml/consume.jsp"><saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://host.tld/java-saml/</saml:Issuer><samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:unspecified" AllowCreate="true"></samlp:NameIDPolicy><samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact"></samlp:RequestedAuthnContext><saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef></samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

results in firefox:

You are now redirected back to http://host.tld/java-saml/consume.jsp If the redirection fails, please click the post button.

Any idea to fix it? In the request or in WSO2IS do I need to configure?

Answer (score 0):

Yes..  It must be the expected behavior, SAML response must be sent as POST from IDP to the SP. (can not use HTTP Redirect) It is defined in the specification. Please check the saml-profile spec. WSO2 identity Server may not support for Artifact binding, therefore it does HTTP POST.

`The identity provider issues a <Response> message to be delivered by the user agent to the service provider. Either the HTTP POST, or HTTP Artifact binding can be used to transfer the message to the service provider through the user agent. The message may indicate an error, or will include (at least) an authentication assertion. The HTTP Redirect binding MUST NOT be used, as the response will typically exceed the URL length permitted by most user agents.`

I guess, POST button and the page that you shown can be changed and modified.